# not able to correclty merge Javascript arrays with underscore

Tags: javascript

i have this function:

```
exports.getRules = function(user) {
  if (!user) {
    return Promise.resolve(null);
  } else {
    return Rule.findAllPr({
      'status': 'published',
      'type': 'price'
    }).then(function(rules) {
      return _.zipObject(rules.map(function(r) {
        var skus;
        skus = _.zipObject(r.sizeIds.map(function(s) {
          return [s, r.discount];
        }));
        return console.log(skus);
      }));
    });
  }
};
```

i am trying to return a combined skus array, currently i am getting two arrays

```
{ 'SA40-MRE0': 5,
  'SA40-MRE1': 5,
  'SA40-MRE2': 5,
  'SA40-MRE3': 5,
  'SA40-MRE4': 5,
  'SA40-MRE5': 5 }
{ 'N50P-IB0': 15,
  'N50P-IB1': 15,
  'N68Z-BL4': 15 }
```

The data comes from mongo as:

```
{
    "__v" : 11,
    "_id" : ObjectId("5627c993dc8c59e63f4b87f6"),
    "discount" : 5,
    "from" : ISODate("2015-10-20T23:00:00Z"),
    "sizeIds" : [
        "SA40-MRE0",
        "SA40-MRE1",
        "SA40-MRE2",
        "SA40-MRE3",
        "SA40-MRE4",
        "SA40-MRE5"
    ],
    "status" : "published",
    "to" : ISODate("2015-10-31T00:00:00Z"),
    "type" : "price"
}
{
    "to" : ISODate("2015-11-02T00:00:00Z"),
    "from" : ISODate("2015-10-22T23:00:00Z"),
    "type" : "price",
    "_id" : ObjectId("562a50e0da1312415f73568c"),
    "status" : "published",
    "sizeIds" : [
        "N50P-IB0",
        "N50P-IB1",
        "N68Z-BL4"
    ],
    "discount" : 15,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Is there a better way to write this code, basically i have two or more mongo documents, for each document, i want to extract the sizeIds and store these in the skus array.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Just as a side note, those two things you're getting are not arrays, as you say. They are plain objects.

Comment: Can you show what your raw data looks like? This can help coming up with a good solution.

Comment: @JoshBeam i have updated my questions

Answer (score 0):

use _.extend

```
exports.getRules = (user) ->
  if !user
    Promise.resolve null
  else
    discountCache = {}
    Rule.findAllPr(
      'status': 'published'
      'type': 'price')
    .then (rules) ->
      _.zipObject rules.map (r) ->
        skus = _.zipObject(r.sizeIds.map((s) ->
          [
            s
            r.discount
          ]
        ))
        extended = _.extend(discountCache, skus)
    .then (skus) ->
      discountCache
```